# good web resources for learning SurfaceView

Tags: android

Does anyone have good web tutorials or resources for learning 2D application development using a SurfaceView (Or something better if it exists).  I am intending on using it for a 2D game but have little experience in this area.

It would be good if it had

1. Creating the Surface View
2. Creating movable graphical objects
3. Collision Detection
4. Basic Game Engine